# Can Tensorflow/Deep Learning be used for Gradient Boosted Trees, Logistic regression?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, tensorflow

Tensorflow and deep learning has mostly been used for Image Processing (Classification, Identification), NLP, Voice and text processing. I have used Spark MLLIB and Mahout in the past? Tensorflow has examples of Deep Neural Network - https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide_and_deep. Can logistic regression, Gradient Boosted Trees etc, be modeled in Tensorflow or a DL Framework?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course. In fact you can find a lot of examples:

There are some ready implementations like tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier in https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide

Or something like this: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/2_BasicModels/logistic_regression.py where you use tf.matmul and appropriate activations.

There is even something with gradient boosting: https://arogozhnikov.github.io/2016/07/05/gradient_boosting_playground.html

Comment: Thanks Andrey. Can you comment on the accuracy of using Tensorflow NN vs something like Scikit learn. The reason I ask is, CNNs have beaten the crap out of traditional machine learning results.

Comment: It really depends on situation. Neural nets usually require a lot of data, more computational resources and more time on model tuning. Also CNN are appliable only to certain problems. Sometimes the problem is easy enough to use usual machine learning models. Also neural nets lack interpretability, which could be necessary in business.